# How to format beautiful plain text email with Thunderbird?

Tags: email, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, formatting, plaintext

I send only plain text emails with Thunderbird. Sometimes, I need some minimalistic formating to facilitate the reading. I wonder how to insert automatically this formating in Thunderbird.

*Is there an easy way (shortcuts for example) to obtain the following results?* In a more general way, I am interested by solutions (addons?) to format plain text in Thunderbird.

### Example 1: Title + box

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Debian Project                               https://www.debian.org/
Debian Project News                    debian-publicity@lists.debian.org
October 27, 2014             https://www.debian.org/News/weekly/2014/14/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this case, I don't know how to 1. align to the right some text and 2. draw a box of dash. Of course, pressing <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> a lot could create the same result but it would be very time consuming and the result will have likely some default (a dash missing, ...).

### Example 2: Title

```
Debian switching back to GNOME as the default desktop
-----------------------------------------------------
```

### Example 3: References

```
See [1] and [2].

  [1] link
  [2] link
```

Comment: Do you realize that, while it's in plain-text, the person viewing it probably isn't using a monospaced font? If they are, then all "formatting" to align things by using whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.) is probably not going to display as intended.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ok but this is not answering my question in any level. I don't care about the fact the formating could lightly differ from what I see and what the other person see. I would like to do quickly and efficiently the formating of example 1 for instance. What can I do? Do you press 100 times "space" and "-"?

Comment: Usually, yeah, or use Tab.

Comment: I realise I'm eighteen months late to this party, but I believe there's an extension that lets you use an external editor for email composition.  A full-featured text editor (I'm partial to emacs, myself, but there are plenty of options) will probably have features that make this kind of formatting much easier.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so there's an easy solution in AutoHotkey -- happy to expand.

Comment: @zx81 not... I'm using Linux (Debian)